# Different ways to print a section of a file

Tags: python, parsing, python-itertools

I understand the python basics and now I'm looking to code more pythonically.

So if I have a text file say like this:

```
This is the start
Text1
Text2

Text3
This is the end
```

I want a script that will go through the file, and pull out only:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
```

So I have this way of doing it:

```
import sys

string = " "
found = False
with open(sys.argv[1]) as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if "Text" in line:
            found = True
        if found:
                string += line
                if "Text3" in line:
                    break

print "\n".join(string.split()) ## I do this to get rid of the line that's just a new line
```

I was wondering if I could do the same more pythonically with itertools somehow?

I was trying something along the lines of:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as input_file:
    for line in iter(input_file.readline,'This is the end\n'):
        print line.strip()
```

But this just prints whitespace. I was wondering if there's a simpler/neater way, that takes less space than my method one, of printing between two lines of text?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. `found` is redundant.
2. Use a list rather than a string when accumulating for concatenation.
3. As only lines that contain Text are added there is no need to filter out empty lines but removing their line endings is useful.
4. If the lines must begin with `Text` rather than just appear anywhere in it then use `if line.startswith("Text"):` instead of `if "Text" in line:`.

Consider:

```py
import sys

L = []
with open(sys.argv[1]) as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if "Text" in line:
            L.append(line.strip())
            if "Text3" in line:
                break

print "\n".join(L)
```